# Find the path and max-weigted edge in a Minimax path-finding solution?

Tags: path-finding, depth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree, minimax, prims-algorithm

I am currently having a programing assignment: given a large weighted unconnected graph (1 < V < 2000,
0 < E < 100 000). Find the maximum-weighted edge along the minimum-weighted path from "source" to point "destination".

What I've got so far is storing the graph in an AdjacencyList (Vector of Vector of IntegerPair where first integer is the neighbor and second is the weight of the edge).

I've also obtained the Minimum Spanning Tree by using Prim's algorithm:

```
private static void process(int vtx) {
  taken.set(vtx, true);

  for (int j = 0; j < AdjList.get(vtx).size(); j++) {
      IntegerPair v = AdjList.get(vtx).get(j);
      if (!taken.get(v.first())) {
          pq.offer(new IntegerPair(v.second(), v.first()));  //sort by weight then by adjacent vertex
      }
   }
}

void PreProcess() {
  Visited = new Vector<Boolean>();
  taken = new Vector<Boolean>(); 
  pq = new PriorityQueue<IntegerPair>();

  taken.addAll(Collections.nCopies(V, false));

  process(0);
  int numTaken = 1;
  int mst_cost = 0;

  while (!pq.isEmpty() && numTaken != V) { //do this until all V vertices are taken (or E = V - 1 edges are taken)
      IntegerPair front = pq.poll();

      if (!taken.get(front.second())) { // we have not connected this vertex yet
          mst_cost += front.first(); // add the weight of this edge
          process(front.second());
          numTaken++;
      }
  }
}
```

What I am stuck at now is how to find the path from source to destination and return the maxmum weight edge in the below query:

```
int Query(int source, int destination) {
 int ans = 0;



 return ans;
}
```

I was told to use Depth-First Search to traverse the resulting MST but I think the DFS will traverse all vertices that are not on the correct path (am I right?). And how to find the maximum edge?

(This problem is not related to any SSSP algorithm because I haven't been taught Dijstra's, etc.)

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with minimax.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to use Kruskal's MST algorithm. It is a greedy algorithm that will start with an empty graph, the repeatedly add the lightest edge that does *not* produce a cycle. This satisfies the properties of a tree, while assuring the minimum-weighted path.

To find the maximum weighted edge, you can also use the properties of the algorithm. Since you know the that EdgeWeight(n) =< EdgeWeight(n+1), the last edge you add to the graph will be the maximum edge.